# How can I render the same texture with different colors?

Tags: colors, 3d, libgdx, textures

I have a very simple texture of a white shape on a black background, and I want the ability to specify a different color for the white part, without changing the source texture:

[image]

Is there a built-in way to do that in libgdx, or will I have to write a custom shader (and if so, what would be the best way to that)?

NOTE: I'm using the 3D api, so my question is in the context of ModelBatch, Materials, and how those are be used to render 3D geometry.

Comment: You could use `SpriteBatch#setColor`, which will tint all `Texture`s rendered with this `SpriteBatch`. That means, that white becomes the tint-color, black stays black and all other colors become a mixture of both. It is also possible to do that with a `PixMap`, which allowes you to manipulate each pixel and create a `Texture` out of it. Note, that if you are using a `TextureAtlas` you will losse its advantages, if you work with the `Texture` you created out of the `PixMap`.

Comment: @Springrbua As the tags imply, I'm using the 3d api, so there is no "SpriteBatch" - I'm using a ModelBatch to draw model instances with accompanying materials.

Comment: Oh i am sorry, i did not see that. You can change the `Material` of each `ModelInstance`, without affecting the original `Model` and other `ModelInstance`s. So you could switch the white `Material` with a green or a blue one. Maybe it is also possible, to add a half-transparent `Material` on top of the `ModelInstance` and with blending enabled it should tint the white parts. Also the way with the `PixMap` should be possible, as you can create a `Texture` out of it, which can then be used as a `Material`.

Comment: @Springrbua All those approaches seem to require multiple textures for multiple colors. I want to have a single texture, which can be rendered in different ways.

Comment: If you use a color instead of a `Texture` you won't need any `Texture`, but it depends on how the final `ModelInstance` should look like. If you do it with `PixMap` you need to store 1 `Texture` only and manipulate it at runtime. You will then have more then one `Texture` arround (1 for each color), but they are not stored in the assets.

Comment: @Springrbua As stated in my question, I want to change the color of a texture portion, so I can't just "use a color instead". As for the pixmap approach: I assume that would work, but it would still generate multiple textures in memory, and that's ugly/wasteful (at least, when compared to my solution below). Either way, thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, if a material has a TextureAttribute.Diffuse, and a ColorAttribute.Diffuse, the color value derived from the texture will be multiplied with the value defined by the color attribute, as can be seen in the [default fragment shader](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g3d/shaders/default.fragment.glsl):

```
#elif defined(diffuseTextureFlag) && defined(diffuseColorFlag)
    vec4 diffuse = texture2D(u_diffuseTexture, v_diffuseUV) * u_diffuseColor;
```

So, for my case, I can simply set the value of the color attribute, and that will produce the desired results -> The black portions of the texture will remain unchanged, because zero (black) multiplied by X will result in zero; The white portions of the texture will change to whatever color is set via the color attribute, because 1 (white) multiplied by X will result in X.